# wtkobfuscate argument problem

Tags: eclipse, ant, proguard

I Have a ant build with this code :

```
<wtkobfuscate jarfile="${dist}/${product.name}.jar"
      jadfile="${dist}/${product.name}.jad"
      verbose="true">
    <classpath>
       <path location="${wtk.home}/lib/j2me-xmlrpc.jar" />
       <!-- path location="${ploc.client}/lib/jarrut-runtime-0.2.jar" / -->
       <pathelement location="${out}/classes" />
    </classpath>
    <argument value=" -keep public class * extends javax.microedition.midlet.MIDlet " />
</wtkobfuscate>
```

This target fine compiled in Linux with eclipse-pulsar.
But fail on windows with equals configuration.

Error log:

```
[wtkobfuscate] proguard.ParseException: Expecting class member name before '}' in argument number 6
[wtkobfuscate]  at proguard.ConfigurationParser.checkJavaIdentifier(ConfigurationParser.java:1116)
[wtkobfuscate]  at proguard.ConfigurationParser.parseMemberSpecificationArguments   (ConfigurationParser.java:812)
[wtkobfuscate]  at proguard.ConfigurationParser.parseClassSpecificationArguments(ConfigurationParser.java:640)
[wtkobfuscate]  at proguard.ConfigurationParser.parseKeepSpecificationArguments(ConfigurationParser.java:462)
[wtkobfuscate]  at proguard.ConfigurationParser.parse(ConfigurationParser.java:118)
[wtkobfuscate]  at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:491)
```

proguard version is 4.2